# Is it possible to make use of touch screen and accelerometer in Android emulator software with touch enabled laptop running Windows 8.1?

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, touch, accelerometer

I'm wondering if it's possible to make use of touch screen and accelerometer on a laptop/ultrabook having multi-touch support screen (to test gestures) and supposedly an accelerometer (because it's able to rotate the screen based on orientation) running Windows 8.1?

The question is not regardind any particular Android emulator, just asking if there are no hardware/software limitations.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hardware or software limitations for this to be possible--it's just a matter of forwarding the touch or accelerometer data to the emulator.

A few different emulators offer the ability to use a connected device for remote control of the emulator. If you want multi-touch support that uses the multi-touch input directly from your laptop screen, try the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx)